# Как ускорить отправку GET запроса

Tags: python, websocket, requests

помогите найти решение.
Подключаюсь через websocket к одной бирже, приходит большой поток информации,примерно 30-40 сообщений в секунду,каждое сообщение мне нужно сравнить с моими данными, если есть нужное, отправить GET запрос. Это нужно сделать максимально быстро, ускорил на сколько смог:
1) мои данный хранятся в словаре и запрашиваю их по ключу, вместо поиска в цикле(это оказалось примерно в 10 раз быстрее)
2) сообщение приходит типа str, но в формате json, нужные мне данные вырезаю что бы не созавать Json объект(это приблизительно в 15 раз быстрее)
3) get запросы отправляю через сессию(не могу оценить на сколько быстрее это происходит чем без сессии)
4) арендовал сервак в Торронто от туда самый маленький ping, тестировал через сервисы в интернете(запрос отправляется в 2 раза быстрее).
И это все мне ни как не помогло, другие боты все равно опережают. Среднее время анализа сообщения и сбор данных перед отправкой 0.0002 сек(до оптимизации было около 0.02), а время отправки запроса и получения ответа от 0.2 до 0.3 (но мне важно лишь получение ответа сервером, посчитать не знаю как, плюс оно еще всегда разное). Есть мысли реализовать это все в cython, либо вообще написать это на Си(пока не знаю как). Но перед тем как вновь тыкать пальцем в небо,решил поинтересоваться у людей которые возможно смогут направить меня на путь истинный.

P.S 
Скорее всего я оптимизировал не то что надо, потому-что понятно что основное время тратится именно на отправку запроса, пытался использовать библиотеки типа faster-than-requests,asincio,aiohttp,но ни что не помогло, возможно не умею гуглить, в общем буду рад любому совету.

Comment: Что значит "get запросы отправляю через сессию"? В питоне не силен

Comment: Сессия используется для сохранентя данных в запросах, т е если при обычном запросе всё остаётся под капотом, то в объекте сессии это можно настроить вручную и сохранить

Comment: Тут важно что бы каждый раз не переоткрывалось соединение

Comment: Session как раз таки keep-alive